# Reuse ASP.NET MVC Views & Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forums

We are having the two different website running for different products (both sites have different MVC projects) . I would like to create the forum software using ASP.NET MVC.

Can any one help how can i reuse Forum (Views & Controller) in two different sites ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out: http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/ You should be able to reuse assemblies and create relative paths.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into [portable areas](http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2009/11/02/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-part-2/) in the [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) project

Answer (score 2):

You could also use .Net Libraries, and then link your controllers to that.